# How to protect home network from DDoS attacks when assigned a static IP that is already known to attackers?

Tags: ddos

Is there something I can do in this case? My ISP says they cannot assign me a different IP. At this stage a VPN no longer helps, correct?

Comment: What, exactly is getting DDoS'ed? Just your normal internet connection, or is there a specific service that is getting hit?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/257038/someone-knows-my-ip-and-is-threatening-to-ddos-me

Comment: @schroeder my connection drops every 3 hours almost on the dot and my ISP has verified that there are no errors on their end. My speed (upload only) gets really low just before and just after my connection drops. I know my IP had been leaked a while ago and have reason too believe 1 individual wants to ddos my network. ISP will be able to confirm tomorrow if it is an attack or not but I just wanted to ask anyways.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a DDoS. Please make sure that you confirm the fault before seeking solutions to an arbitrary potential problem.

Comment: You can log into admin on your router, usually there is a firewall log that will pick up on security threats. Last time my connection got like this I just needed to replace the splitter, so it was a hardware issue for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get another ISP. Or find a way to get another IP (did you try to restart the router?).

A VPN will do absolutely nothing. That protects your outgoing traffic from inspection. It is not the correct tool for an incoming flood.

If the ISP can't help you, then there is nothing you can do against a DDoS against your home IP.

Comment: my isp is the only one in the area and only has static IPs. they will not reassign you a new one. I've got no choice but to move if I want a new IP. Thank you for your answer

Comment: My guess from this detail is that you share an IP with others in your area. That's a reason why you can't get a new one. Which also suggests other traffic issues that could affect your connection.

Comment: You can get a new IP without getting a new ISP, put the connection into bridge mode or modem mode depending on your ISP, and just attach it to a new router, you will have a new IP through this mode. After a month or two you can disable this mode and unplug the new router and the chances are you will get assigned a new IP even without this mode. IP addresses are on a lease and even static IPs are not permanent, I recently took a trip abroad and got a new IP when I got back. Somebody else likely has my old IP now because there is not enough to go around with ISPs still mostly using ipv4.

Comment: @Coderxyz you are making ***many*** assumptions about ISPs. There are some ISPs, especially in remote areas, where you get assigned an IP and it never changes, even if you change hardware. Also, there are some ISPs that have customers share a single IP. So, yes, there are cases where the only way to get an IP is to change ISPs. The OP says that the ISP can't give them a new IP, and I'm going by that at face value, because it is plausible.

Comment: @schroeder I have been told the same thing by ISPs before and still got mine to change. Without knowing his ISP it is also making too many assumptions to say switch ISP, several ISP staff will tell you it is not possible, without knowing certain configurations force a change. I have had my fair share of inept information from ISPs. As for shared IPs, I believe that is more common amongst mobile phones. You said "there is nothing you can do against a DDoS against your home IP." but that depends on his ISP.

Comment: @Coderxyz but that's still based on your assumption that the ISP is wrong. You simply don't know that. I offer advice based on the ISP being right, ***and*** offer the typical advice one would normally give. I don't know why you are fixated on this when all you have is your personal experience *and* an admitted lack of info where you conclude that there is no other possibility despite someone with different experience saying otherwise. So, frankly, I have no idea what you're on about.

Comment: @schroeder ISP said I couldn't change my static IP, I called them back the next day and asked them for a new router and that did change my IP. Most of the time, a new router will force an IP change. That is because the MAC address will be different and the old IP is tied to the old MAC address on some systems, so the DHCP server will see the IP as still on the lease time and force a new one. As mentioned, above I have also changed IP when forcing my router to be a modem and connecting it to a new router before, several times I have been told something is impossible by ISPs and it was not.

Comment: @schroeder also, you said "there is nothing you can do against a DDoS against your home IP.". This isn't true either, you can block unused ports on the router for a start.

Comment: @Coderxyz you are still replacing someone else's experience with your own anecdotal experience. That's nice you experienced that. But that ***is not true for everyone***. And blocking unused ports on your router ***will do nothing against a DDoS***. It's not clear that you understand the situation here or how the situation can be.